# Linux and multiple audio lines in Java

Tags: java, linux, audio, raspberry-pi, javasound

I am trying to open several SourceDataLines in Java, and while it works on my Windows PC, it gives an error on my Raspberry Pi (soft-float Raspbian Linux)

> "line with format PCM_SIGNED 22050.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian not      supported"

when I am trying to request the 2nd one from the same Mixer (first one is fine). The Mixer should probably support multiple lines as it writes:

> " ALSA [default], version 1.0.24 interface SourceDataLine supporting 84 audio formats, supports 8 lines"

Any suggestions on how to make several audio SourceDataLines or realize sound mixing with multiple threads?

Comment: has anyone solved this? I have no problem playing two files simultaneously with the HDMI or 3.5mm jack, but I get the same error when using a USB DAC. After a day of troubleshooting, I came to think the error should read 'Additional line not supported" as the file will play just fine if it's not trying for the 2nd line. I would like to use the DAC for output, so I can use its input to stream the mixed audio at the same time (with different software). I can do this in Win7 without errors.